# change node spacing among some nodes | tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-node

I am struggling with what my options might be to change the spacing among particular nodes in a tikzpicture/matrix I'm trying to construct. The MWE (at the bottom) generates the following. Which is close -- but what I'm trying to do is reduce the spacing between what is node 3 and 4 (where node 4 is 'empty', filled with \cdots), and then 4 and 5 (to, say, approximately half of what is now). I've had a look at tikzpositioning, but if that's the right direction, haven't sussed out how to get what I'm looking for.  Thanks in advance for suggestions.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \rule[-1.85cm]{0pt}{3.5cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,transform canvas={scale=1.05},line width=0.75pt]
 \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=4em, every node/.style={circle,draw,font=\small,minimum width=1cm},
 1.node/.style={font=\bf\small\sffamily,fill=blue!20},
 2.node/.style={font=\bf\small\sffamily,fill=green!10},
 3.node/.style={font=\bf\small\sffamily,fill=green!20},
 m.node/.style={font=\bf\small\sffamily,fill=green!30},
 empty.node/.style={draw=none}] 
 {|[1.node]|1 & |[2.node]|2  & |[3.node]|3  & |[empty.node]|$\cdots$ & |[m.node]|m \\};
 % left to right, right to left
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(-0.4pt,-2.25pt)}}] (a-1-1) edge  (a-1-2);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(-0.4pt,-2.25pt)}}] (a-1-2) edge  (a-1-3);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(-0.4pt,-2.25pt)}}] (a-1-3) edge (a-1-4);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(-0.4pt,-2.25pt)}}] (a-1-4) edge (a-1-5);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(0.4pt, 2.25pt)}}] (a-1-5) edge  (a-1-4);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(0.4pt, 2.25pt)}}] (a-1-4) edge  (a-1-3);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(0.4pt, 2.25pt)}}] (a-1-3) edge  (a-1-2);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small, transform canvas={shift={(0.4pt, 2.25pt)}}] (a-1-2) edge (a-1-1);
 % returning arcs
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge [bend right=50]  (a-1-1) ;
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [bend right=60]  (a-1-1) ;
 % self-loops
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=305, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm]  (a-1-1) ;
 % smaller nested-loop
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge [dotted, loop, below, out=250, in=290, looseness=10, distance=0.45cm]  (a-1-1) ;
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm]  (a-1-2) ;
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm]  (a-1-3) ;
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-5) edge [loop, below, out=240, in=300, looseness=10, distance=0.9cm]  (a-1-5) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can use for example `&[2em]` to change the column seperation for that one time. The `positioning` library has no bearing on a `\matrix`.

Comment: Perfect -- that does the trick. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5cm, arrows={-{Stealth[length=3pt]}, shorten >=1pt}, cells={nodes={draw, circle, minimum size=8mm, fill=green!10}}]
|[fill=blue!20]|1\arrow[r, yshift=-2pt]\arrow[loop below, out=240, in=300, looseness=4]\arrow[dotted, loop below, out=250, in=290, looseness=3.5] & 
2\arrow[l, yshift=2pt]\arrow[r, yshift=-2pt]\arrow[l, bend right=45]\arrow[loop below, out=240, in=300, looseness=4] & 
3\arrow[l, yshift=2pt]\arrow[r, yshift=-2pt]\arrow[ll, bend right=60]\arrow[loop below, out=240, in=300, looseness=4] &[-5mm]
|[draw=none, fill=none]|\cdots\arrow[l, yshift=2pt]\arrow[r, yshift=-2pt] &[-5mm]
m\arrow[l, yshift=2pt]\arrow[loop below, out=240, in=300, looseness=4]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also with `tikz-cd` package but with use of `tikzset˙ for defi9ne loops some columns styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{Loop/.style = {loop below, out=240, in=300, looseness=5},
         execute at end node=\vphantom{4},
         bend angle=45,
         column 3/.style = {column sep=7mm},
         column 4/.style = {column sep=7mm}
        }

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5cm,
                   arrows={-Stealth, shorten >=1pt},
                   cells={nodes={draw, circle, minimum size=8mm, inner sep=0pt, fill=green!10}},
                   ]
|[fill=blue!30]| 1  \rar[shift left]
                    \ar[Loop] \ar[loop below, densely dotted, out=250, in=290, looseness=5]
        & 2 \lar[shift left]\rar[shift left]\lar[bend right]
            \ar[Loop]
                & 3 \lar[shift left]\rar[shift left]\lar[bend right]
                    \ar[Loop]
                        & |[draw=none,fill=none]|\cdots \lar[shift left]\rar[shift left] 
                                & m \lar[shift left] 
                                    \ar[Loop]   
    \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]